# Ошибка в строке bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

Tags: python, discord.py

Код:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# Конфигурация Selenium
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Запуск браузера в фоновом режиме
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


# Конфигурация Дискорд бота
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot connected: {bot.user.name}")


@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Start...")

    # Переход на сайт Aternos
    driver.get("https://aternos.org/go")

    # Вход в аккаунт
    login_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user")))
    password_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
    login_input.send_keys("секрет")
    password_input.send_keys("секрет")
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Ожидание загрузки страницы сервера
    wait.until(EC.url_to_be("https://aternos.org/server"))

    # Проверка состояния сервера
    status_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".statuslabel-label")))
    server_status = status_button.text

    if server_status == "Offline":
        # Нажатие кнопки "Включить"
        start_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".start")))
        start_button.click()
        await ctx.send("Server is starting...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Server is on.")


# Запуск бота
bot.run("")
```

Ошибка:

```
 3.17s - Error in linecache.getline('D:\\Павел\\Эксперименты\\DiscordBot\\main.py', 19, f_globals)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 546, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame._handle_exception
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 360: invalid continuation byte
0.00s - Error on build_exception_info_response.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1452, in build_exception_info_response
    line_text = linecache.getline(original_filename, lineno)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 360: invalid continuation byte
0.03s - Error on build_exception_info_response.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1452, in build_exception_info_response
    line_text = linecache.getline(original_filename, lineno)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\pahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 360: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Покажите весь ваш код. По одной строке мы не сможем вам помочь.

Comment: изменил свой пост

Comment: @Глеб я изменил свой пост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(config['prefix'], intents=intents)
```

во всех моих ботах используется эти строчки, попробуйте

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Остальное вас вообще не смутило? То есть, что в коде самой первой строчкой объявляется bot (без импортов) и только потом уже идёт импорт commands вас совсем не смутило?

Comment: лол, я даже не заметил, мне кажется он случайно, потом у него снова объявляется bot. Да, он вначале отправил одну строчку, затем ему написали в комментарии, чтобы он добавил весь код и видимо просто вставил свой код вместе со своей проблемной строчкой